# Do long distance business jets have a crew resting area?

Tags: aircraft-design, general-aviation

I am asking this question out of curiosity. Do they have separate cabin area for themselves?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Gulfstream, FalconJet and Bombardier all offer a small crew rest space in their large cabin business jets, depending on the cabin configuration.  This isn’t similar to those found on airliners, but it does feature a normal sized and reclining seat with seatbelts, a small table, lighting, emergency oxygen and a divider for privacy from the other passengers.

Answer (score 4):

The interior configuration is the choice of the operator and for most business jets is done at a separate completion center (although Bombardier does Global interiors in-house) where the interior is certified under an STC. The airplane will leave the factory "green" (no interior or paint) to go to a completion center of the purchaser's choosing.

The owner can choose to put in a crew rest area and may even include a sleeping bunk.  It'll depend on the owner's mission profile, and how that profile affects the complicated duty period regulations the operator is subjected to. They may just put in a partitioned area with a seat and amenities, or may include a full size sleeping bunk if a relief pilot is required to be on board to meet rest period regulations.

Answer (score 1):

Crew rest area or compartment is a separate area of an airplane which *may not* be accessible to passengers. Depending on the class<sup>1</sup> of the airplane, crew may have a rest area with isolated resting places, or a flat seat separated by a curtain or a seat which can recline and has foot support.

In the US, FAA has detailed about rest areas in [14 CFR Part 117](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-117). Accompanied by the advisory circular [AC-117](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_117-1.pdf), the classes are:

> **Class 1 Rest Facility** Means a bunk or other surface that allows for a flat sleeping position and is located separate from both the
> flight deck and passenger cabin in an area that is
> temperature-controlled, allows the flight crew member to control
> light, and provides isolation from noise and disturbance.
>
> **Class 2 Rest Facility** Means a seat in an aircraft cabin that allows for a flat or near flat sleeping position; is separated from
> passengers by a minimum of a curtain to provide darkness and some
> sound mitigation; and is reasonably free from disturbance by
> passengers or flight crew members.
>
> **Class 3 Rest Facility** Means a seat in an aircraft cabin or flight deck that reclines at least 40 degrees and provides leg and foot
> support

The above circular also provides details about the dimensions of each class and the facilities which are required.

---

1: Class of an airplane depends on the number of crew and the duration of the flight.

Comment: Not sure that anything in Part 117 applies to biz jets? It certainly governs Part 121 operations, but most biz jets are Part 91 operations, or 135 if they're chartered. Does Part 117 apply to those?